# heroku "cannot convert nil into string"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, null

I am using ruby on rails4 , and trying to deploy to heroku. However, when I try to run 
      "heroku run rake db:migrate", I am getting following error.

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.8591
rake aborted!
TypeError: can't convert nil into String 
/app/config/initializers/devise.rb:13:in `+'
/app/config/initializers/devise.rb:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/devise-66db52ce31b5/lib/devise.rb:292:in   `setup'
/app/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport- 4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:379:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
  Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise'
gem 'pundit'


gem 'mail_form'
gem 'simple_form'

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_19]
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
end
group :development, :test do
   gem 'factory_girl_rails'
   gem 'rspec-rails'
end
group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

gem 'pg'
gem 'validates_formatting_of'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'

gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
gem "less-rails"
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'


gem 'bundler'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'


gem 'haml'                # or gem 'slim'
gem 'awesome_nested_set'  # or same gem
```

This is database.yml

```
 default: &default
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
```

This is application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require 'devise'
# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Korffice
  class Application < Rails::Application

   config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec,
        fixtures: true,
        view_specs: false,
        helper_specs: false,
        routing_specs: false,
        controller_specs: false,
        request_specs: false
     g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: "spec/factories"
    end

    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
    config.serve_static_assets = true

  end
end
```

This is secrets.yml

```
development:
  admin_name: First User
  admin_email: user@example.com
  admin_password: changeme
  email_provider_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
  email_provider_password: <%= ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"] %>
  domain_name: example.com
  secret_key_base:   98b154040ed274afa3f122e5b3a4f18cac77ac62465b709d94c61e93300bec895ac3b3aa127ad2a8ac5e1a18c894c01c5c61f1f71f0e391dfad6d2b43f781816

test:
  domain_name: example.com 
  secret_key_base: 1a32266f762d172de9f3f9eb52750ee7f8ec8196e77cc940c6eb754ce8ffa4fc93d82682daaad83beba9b2bf25303455a3c149be4092445637de875c6b375489

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  admin_name: <%= ENV["ADMIN_NAME"] %>
  admin_email: <%= ENV["ADMIN_EMAIL"] %>
  admin_password: <%= ENV["ADMIN_PASSWORD"] %>
  email_provider_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
  email_provider_password: <%= ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"] %> 
  domain_name: <%= ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"] %>
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

This is devise.rb

```
 Devise.setup do |config|
      config.mailer_sender = 'no-reply@' + Rails.application.secrets.domain_name
      require 'devise/orm/active_record'
     config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
     config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]
     config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
     config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
     config.reconfirmable = true
     config.password_length = 8..128
     config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
     config.sign_out_via = :delete
  end
```

Please help :(

Comment: My guess is that `Rails.application.secrets.domain_name` is nil... I'd look at how you are supposed to set that up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you deploy to heroku it requires `domain_name`, that for **development** you have set it as string as: `example.com`.

In **production** it expects the domain name to be set in variable: `<%= ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"] %>` that on heroku is not set as you do it on local machine.

To make use of env variables in heroku you can use [figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro#heroku).

Comment: I have done gem "figaro" --> "rails generate figaro:install"->"rake figaro:heroku" following "https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro/tree/0-stable". But even after I do this, I am still getting the same error :(

Comment: You could try to change `<%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>` variable to plain string, like `mydomain.com` and deploy to heroku, if you don't get the error you have now, it means you did not set up figaro properly. Also look for heorku figrao addon, if I am not mistaken you need to add an addon for this.

Comment: When did Heroku require `domain_name`?

Comment: @RichPeck, you are asking me?

Comment: Anyone who knows the answer :D

Comment: @RichPeck - devise configurations `config.mailer_sender = 'no-reply@' + Rails.application.secrets.domain_name`, he wants to merge `string` with `nil`

Comment: Yeah but what about Heroku itself? That doesn't need a `domain_name` attribute, right?

Comment: No, Heroku doesn't need a `domain_name` attribute. Devise does. And you're using Devise on Heroku, so you need to set it there otherwise it (Devise/Rails) throws the exception you're seeing.

Comment: @GlennGillen when I said "it requires" I didn't meant heroku requires, I meant app requires `<%= ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"] %>` that was not set. Even if Devise requires it, this variable is set by ENV so it shoud e set correctly. Or you suggest we go to devise config and set it there hard-coded?

Comment: @magnum2002 I know :) I was replying to Richard.

Comment: @GlennGillen oops, my bad. I wasn't reading his comment above. ;)

Answer (score 2):

To give you another perspective, I looked at this answer: [Deploying Rails App to Heroku Keeps Crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904136/deploying-rails-app-to-heroku-keeps-crashing)

---

**Devise**

I don't know if `Heroku` requires you to set your `domain_name` (I've not deployed there for a while), but regardless, I'd say the issue is more with `Devise`:

> app/config/initializers/devise.rb:13:in `+'

It looks like you're getting the error when you assign the `email` for Devise, which you do here:

```
#config/initializers/devise.rb
config.mailer_sender = 'no-reply@' + Rails.application.secrets.domain_name
```

The problem you have is that you've set your `domain_name` in your **secrets** for your development environment; and used an `ENV` variable for the `domain_name` in production.

--

**ENV Vars**

To fix this, you need to make sure you have the `ENV` variables set up on Heroku. To do this, you need to appreciate [what an ENV variable is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) (it's nothing to do with [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro))

> ENV (Environment) variables sit on the operating system & allow
>   applications to access a pool of (often secret) data, which can be
>   used throughout the application. ENV variables are generally used to
>   store sensitive data (such as `API` keys), mainly to decouple that
>   data from the application itself (to make the system more secure)

It looks like you haven't got the environment variable for your `DOMAIN_NAME` set up. To do this, you'll be best using Heroku's CLI (command line interface) to [set it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars):

```
$ heroku config:set DOMAIN_NAME=your_domain.com
```

Comment: Heroku itself is not requiring any domain name, but based on his code from devise he needs this variable, so the problem with heroku is just that app crashes at start up because of missing variable. Your answer is just an extended version of mine, and it HAS TO DO with Figaro, cause using Figaro you can set variables on heroku. I do a lot of deployments on heroku and I am sure I am right.

Comment: Yes you're right - my answer is an extension of yours; hence why I alluded to that at the start (don't mean to detract, it's just better to get two opinions for the OP). In regards to Figaro - this only sets the ENV vars. Whilst technically this *is* to do with the issue, it's not the actual fix -- the actual fix is to set the ENV var. You can, of course, do that *through* Figaro, but whether you do or don't, the answer is not dependent on Figaro being used

Comment: I only know because I've spent days myself fixing issues pertaining to ENV vars on Heroku :)

Comment: But if he uses `heroku config:set DOMAIN_NAME=your_domain.com` he will have to use this command each time he does a restart on heroku, cause all variables are gone when you do that. That seems like a very annoying thing to specially when you have a lot of keys. At least this what we did before using figaro, we had to push keys each time we did heroku restart.

Comment: The ENV vars are stored at OS-level (typically in `.bashrc` or `/etc/environment` when using linux - which is what Heroku uses); you can restart Heroku all you like without them being reset. I think you're alluding to [SHELL variables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-using-variables.htm) which are deleted after each shell session

Comment: `Figaro` does this programmatically - `Figaro parses a Git-ignored YAML file in your application and loads its values into ENV`; which means that although you are right that you *can* use Figaro, it's not the underlying solution, just a way to solve it

Comment: SHELL variables, that must be it.. well then, as you mentioned `heroku config:set DOMAIN_NAME=your_domain.com` should be more than enough. Got to try this into our apps. Cheers.

Comment: A good example of a SHELL var is `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` -- this sets the rails environment as "production" for the duration of that function call

Comment: The Heroku config set only sets the ENV vars for the Heroku environment variables. This just sets the variables in the `bashrc` file of Heroku's linux instance (as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)). Figaro is great for setting the variables for multiple environments; I wanted to recommend that `Figaro` itself is not the solution, merely a way to achieve it. It doesn't mean your answer is wrong; far from it. It just means the OP should know about the underlying solution -- the ENV vars

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had set `DOMAIN_NAME` etc inside secret.yml and this file was git ignored since I wanted to keep credentials private. So Heroku couldn't find these configuration values.

Using figaro gem seems a good way to fix this. But I didn't want to add another gem and create a new yml file.

What I did was **set Heroku environment variables** directly and it worked:

```
$ heroku config:add GMAIL_USERNAME='myname@gmail.com' GMAIL_PASSWORD='mypassword'
$ heroku config:add DOMAIN_NAME='example.com'
```